# Share post to multiple friends with Facebook SDK 3.0+ - Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

Is there any way to post story to multiple friends walls?

I have a list of my friends ids , and when i make the dialog for sharing in this moment i am passing "TO" param with just one friend id. Should i open dialog for each friend (this is not so user friendly) ?

Answer (score 0):

The "to" parameter only allows to specify one friend, just let the user add other friends on his own in that dialog - or omit the "to" parameter completely, which is probably the best solution.

Comment: That's ok. I am asking if there is any way to post on more friends walls at once ? To pass String[] of ids, or something like that ?